# How do I programatically list all routes in .NET Core Web API project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-routing

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API where routes are not matched. It works fine locally, but it's not working on the server. The logs show me

> No candidates found for the request path

but I see the request path and it is correct.

I would like to log all the routes, just to see what my application thinks are the routes. It may help to see what is different on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

1. Add `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` (from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure`) as a parameter to `Configure(...)` within `Startup.cs`.
2. Iterate over `ActionDescriptors` of `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider`.

**Example**

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger log, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionProvider)
{
    // configuration

    app.UseMvc();

    var routes = actionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
        .Where(x => x.AttributeRouteInfo != null);

    foreach(var route in routes)
    {
        log.LogDebug($"{route.AttributeRouteInfo.Template}");
    }
}
```

Comment: For ASP.NET Core 6, when you don't have a `Configure` method, you can get the action provider thus, before calling `app.Run()`: `var actionProvider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();`

Comment: Can you explain how `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` compares to `EndpointDataSource` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `Swagger`. It is a very common tool that lists all of the API controllers, endpoints and models. Setting it up for .Net 5 is well documented in Microsoft's sources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-5.0#swagger-ui

Comment: 90% percent of questions here are from the people who decided to use Swagger.

Comment: So how does the swagger does this so that I can use this in my code? Eg for integration or funcional testing of my API.

Comment: Swagger provides kind-of a frontend view that is useful to see all methods in the API.
For manual testing it might be OK, but for testing an API I would go another way - simply creating a test project and testing the endpoints one-by-one.